# How to connect to Postgres Amazon-RDS from TypeORM?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, typeorm

Have tried to connect to my RDS Postgres instance from postgres client (Docker image)...

```
docker run -it --rm jbergknoff/postgresql-client postgresql://username:******@somepostgres.sometext.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
```

and it works...

When I try it from typeorm... it complain about getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND.

Here is my connection option:

```
{
  type: 'postgres',
      logging: true,
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: 5432,
      username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: true,
      extra: {
        ssl: true
      }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
[Nest] 25882   - 06/09/2019, 12:19 PM   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... +3291ms
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres.sometext.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com postgres.sometext.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com.com:5432
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:58:26)
```

EDIT:
When I use the IP. it works. But still curious... why the address not working tho.

EDIT 2:

Found it. My local node js can't connect to RDS because my nameserver is not configured correctly.

To fix it in linux you do it like,

```
# /etc/resolv.conf

# I use google here
nameserver 8.8.8.8
namaserver 8.8.4.4
```

And the reason why i can access it from docker, i guess docker have its own nameserver configuration.